# Wiring harness replacement for older Isuzu FTR medium duty

Tags: isuzu, wiring-diagram, parts-replacement, wiring-harness

Rodents had the bright idea to build a nest on top of our 2002 Isuzu FTR and the resulting fire destroyed a bunch of sensors, hoses, and wiring.

Our mechanic has been trying for a month and a half to find the main wiring harness replacement with no luck. He said usually he can rebuild the wiring but it's so bad he can't see the old wire coloring anymore to match up wire to wire and the electrical drawings aren't helpful either.

Apparently this part is not made anymore so what do mechanics do other than contacting junk yard after junk yard looking for parts? Are there places that know how to 3d print the harness without the wires?

We'd hate to think this truck is now a 15,000lb yard ornament now because of a wiring harness since it still is very young on miles....

Is there some secret source for parts that maybe the mechanic isn't tuned into? Would appreciate any leads as to how we can fix this truck.

Comment: I just did a google search for "custom engine wiring harness" and several manufacturers of wiring harnesses were listed, for example - https://atleadsandlooms.co.uk/services/electrical-wiring-looms-cable-forms-cable-harness/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgK2qBhCHARIsAGACuzls-ImaKrqhaI86lSu9rvIb1XvCUYTDtG4nvXcRP22AUvy0gu9eca8aAjvoEALw_wcB I am sure most of them will be able to make what you need.